# Will Doctrine2 select all fields on all associations (JOINS from a query) to populate the full aggregate object?

Tags: doctrine-orm, aggregation

I'm researching whether to try Doctrine2 or not. One thing that scares me is the over SELECTing of columns I don't need (ie. consider lots of varchars being selected unnecessarily).

You might ask: *but don't you want your full entity object filled?* Yes, unless I'm looking for an array hydration. However, many times I don't need the full aggregation filled. Take the association shown below. If I query the Users table with a JOIN on Address, will all the columns from the address table be SELECTed as well (and therefore populated into an address object inside of users object)? Now imagine we have more JOINs. This could get really bad. What if I only want the fields from User populated in just a users only object? I guess I'm a little confused at what Doctrine is doing behind the scenes with associations and query JOINs.

```
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $address;
}

/** @Entity **/
class Address
{
    // ...
}
```

So does Doctrine2 populate all the fields of all the objects within the aggregate after a query (unless I specifiy `partial`)?

Comment: Yes.  If you query with an explicit join then, by default, Doctrine will populate all the fields.  You can use partial to select fields.  Doctrine does focus on objects and partially hydrated objects can cause issues.  Keep in mind that for large reporting type queries you can always drop down to sql.

Comment: Yeah this is upsetting. Consider I've got varchars and text fields I don't always need (now imagine that multiplied by the other associations and their text fields). But I guess it's not completely upsetting, because there really is no way to eat my cake and have it to, here.

Comment: If you want to make your comment an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your query, but generally it is not implicit.
Using the query builder, you can fetch the associated record like this:

```
<?php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select(array("u", "a"))
        ->from("User", "u")
        ->innerJoin("u.address", "a")
        ->getQuery();
```

In the select() statement you specify what to fetch, in this case you get both.

If you only fetch the User records, then when you get the associated record with $user->getAddress(), Doctrine will make the query on the fly and hydrate the Address record for you.

That said, performance wise it is better to select both entities so Doctrine will make only one query and not 1+N queries

Comment: Ah, that is clear and makes sense. Thank you. So I guess that areas of your app that accept this Users domain object should be aware that there could be a problem by using the data of its associations? Since you are potentially causing the database to query without knowing it, I think this could lead to a little fast-and-loose programming, or your services have to be extra cautious (seems like not much was gained by this Doctine convenience when you have to think/write code to cover for this). It might be better to only offer 2 flavors: hard object collections (that go so deep), and arrays.

Comment: Well, associated records are queried by primary key, which is fast even if you have to fetch a few 10s of rows. But yes, you have to be careful if you more than a few joined tables. Generally I log SQL queries so it's easy for me to find performance issues due to crazy amount of queries been executed by Doctrine